# I want to make SQL tables that are updated daily yet retain every single day's contents for later lookup. What is the best practice for this?

Tags: sql, database-design

Basically I'm trying to create a database schema based around multiple unrelated tables that will not need to reference each other AFAIK.

Each table will be a different "category" that will have the same columns in each table - name, date, two int values and then a small string value.

My issue is that each one will need to be "updated" daily, but I want to keep a record of the items for every single day.

What's the best way to go about doing this? Would it be to make the composite key the combination of the date and the name? Or use something called a "trigger"?

Sorry I'm somewhat new to database design, I can be more specific if I need to be.

Comment: what mean `each one` will need be updated daily? each table, each row, each item?

Comment: Each one means each table. It's essentially an inventory/production item thing. So monday would have wood, how many benches we need to make, how many we have, etc. The rest of the days of the week would have the same exact columns but every day would need unique values/to be updated without losing the old information.

Comment: And off the question, instead of multiple tables. You should create/add  a field `category_id` and save all the data in a single table. That is a better design. Also next time a small sample with some data will help to give you a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a trigger for each `category` table

I'm assuming `name` is PK for each table? If isnt the case, you will need create a PK.

Lets say you have

```
 table categoryA
 name, date, int1, int2, string

 table categoryB
 name, date, int1, int2, string
```

You will create another table to store changes log.

```
 table category_history
 category_table, name, date, int1, int2, string, changeDate
```

You create two trigger, one for each category table

Where you save what table gerate the update and what time was made.

```
 create trigger before update for categoryA
     INSERT INTO category_history VALUES
       ('categoryA', OLD.name, OLD.date, OLD.int1, Old.int2, OLD.string, NOW());
```

This is pseudo code, you need write trigger using your rdbms syntaxis, and check how get system date `now()`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, it is poor design to have different identical tables for each category. Better would be a Categories table with one entry for each category and then a Dailies table with the daily information.

```
create table Categories(
    ID    smallint  not null auto_generated,
    Name  varchar( 20 ) not null,
    ...,      -- other information about each category
    constraint UQ_Category_Name unique( Name ),
    constraint PK_Categories( ID )
);
create table Dailies(
    CatID   smallint not null,
    UpdDate date not null,
    ..., -- Daily values
    constraint PK_Dailies( CatID, UpdDate ),
    constraint FK_Dailies_Category foreign key( CatID )
        references Categories( ID )
);
```

This way, adding a new category involves inserting a row into the Categories table rather than creating an entirely new table.

If the database has a `Date` type distinct from a `DateTime` -- no time data -- then fine. Otherwise, the time part must be removed such as by Oracle's `trunc` function. This allows only one entry for each category per day.

Retrieving all the values for all the posted dates is easy:

```
select  C.Name as Category, d.UpdDate, d.<daily values>
from    Categories C
join    Dailies    D
    on  D.CatID = C.ID;
```

This can be made into a view, DailyHistory. To see the complete history for Category Cat1:

```
select  *
from    DailyHistory
where   Name = 'Cat1';
```

To see all the category information as it was updated on a specific date:

```
select  *
from    DailyHistory
where   UpdDate = date '2014-05-06';
```

Most queries will probably be interested in the current values -- that is, the last update made (assuming some categories are not updated every day). This is a little more complicated but still very fast if you are worried about performance.

```
select  C.Name as Category, d.UpdDate as "Date", d.<daily values>
from    Categories C
join    Dailies    D
    on  D.CatID = C.ID
    and D.UpdDate =(
            select  Max( UpdDate )
            from    Dailies
            where   CatID = D.CatID );
```

Of course, if every category is updated every day, the query is simplified:

```
select  C.Name as Category, d.UpdDate as "Date", d.<daily values>
from    Categories C
join    Dailies    D
    on  D.CatID = C.ID
    and D.UpdDate = <today's date>;
```

This can also be made into a view. To see today's (or the latest) updates for Category Cat1:

```
select  *
from    DailyCurrent
where   Name = 'Cat1';
```

Suppose now that updates are not necessarily made every day. The history view would show all the updates that were actually made. So the query shown for all categories as they were on a particular day would actually show only those categories that were actually *updated* on that day. What if you wanted to show the data that was "current" as of a particular date, even if the actual update was several days before?

That can be provided with a small change to the "current" query (just the last line added):

```
select  C.Name as Category, d.UpdDate as "Date", d.<daily values>
from    Categories C
join    Dailies    D
    on  D.CatID = C.ID
    and D.UpdDate =(
            select  Max( UpdDate )
            from    Dailies
            where   CatID = D.CatID
                and UpdDate <= date '2014-05-06' );
```

Now this shows all categories with the data updated on that date if it exists otherwise the latest update made previous to that date.

As you can see, this is a very flexible design which allows access the data just about any way desired.